# oracle apex update statement (using return value of select list and text_field)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

```
update student set :P9_COLUMNNAME = :P9_VALUE
```

This is my attempt but it returns

> ORA06550 error invalid user.table column, table.column or column specification.

Usually when i set the value from user input it works well but this time oracle doesn't allow me to pass the column value in this way. Did anyone encountered the same problem? Thanks in advance

p.s. `P9_columnname` is a selectlist and `p9_value` is a textfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCorV.png)

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` should be used to update a table column, not an item in your Apex application.

So, it is either

```
update student set 
  some_column = :P9_VALUE
  where ...   --> don't forget the WHERE clause, otherwise you'll update the whole table
```

or

```
:P9_COLUMNNAME := :P9_VALUE;
```

---

If Select List item contains column names, you'll have to use dynamic SQL. For example:

```
declare
  l_str varchar2(200);
begin
  l_str := 'update student set ' || :P9_COLUMNNAME || ' = ' || :P9_VALUE;
  execute immediate l_str;
end;
```

Don't forget the `where` clause!

Comment: I have tried "update student set :P9_COLUMNNAME := :P9_value;" but i got the same error

Comment: i want 'some_column' to be an input from user (selection of select list) in this case, instead of a static value

Comment: Aha, select list returns list of column names. If that's so, you'll have to use **dynamic SQL**.

Comment: thank you very much bro. i am really new in oracle, you helped me a lot. wish you a Merry Christmas bro

Comment: declare
  l_str varchar2(200);
begin
  l_str := 'UPDATE STUDENT SET ' || :P9_COLUMN || ' = ' || :P9_NEWVALUE || ' WHERE SRN = ' || :P9_STUDENTNO;
  execute immediate l_str;
end; but no matter what i enter for new value, it returns ORA-00904 "value": invalid identifier for execute pl/sql code, i have changed it to hardcode 'value' but the error is the same, it is not caused by the returned double quote

Comment: It looks as if P9 page's item's values aren't stored in session state. The simplest way to do so is to create a button which **submits** the page. Code you wrote should be put into a **process** which runs when that button is pressed.

Comment: now my dynamic action is to run the code when the button is clicked. what should i change? im confused

Comment: What *dynamic action*? I told you to create a **process**.

Comment: thank you, u helped me a lot in this problem and it is now really solved!